# In IE only text part of link is clickable

Tags: html, css, haslayout

I just noticed that in IE9 and IE8 (not in IE7) the padding around my links is not being considered part of the link (it's not clickable and my hover effects aren't being applied when it's hovered over). Only the text part of the link is working.

I tried giving the element a background color but that didn't fix it.

Has anyone seen this before?

SOLVED: Wrote a huge edit to my question and in the process figured it out myself. 
I had a negative z-index on the body, which I definitely didn't know would cause this but apparently it does. Here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CEbMe/ which shows the problem in IE9 and IE8

Comment: Can you setup a specific demo with your issue (jsBin, jsFiddle) or just paste some code?

Comment: I just tested on IE 9, and it has no difficulties in making the entire link, including padding, clickable. So there’s something special involved in your code if things don’t work that way.

Comment: Thanks guys! I just accepted some answers, sorry should have gotten on that earlier...

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
<style>
  a { display: inline-block; padding: 0 50px; background: yellow; }
</style>
<p>This is a <a href="#">link</a> with some text around it</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the suggested answers fixed it for me, and I spent a few hours finding the answer:

http://haslayout.net/css/Partial-Click-Bug-v2

```
background-image: url(#);
```

fixes it. I imagine this would probably do the job too:

```
background-color: transparent;
```